# matplotlib text logo - change width

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a logo (in matplotlib) that looks like this-

[image: 1]

The two letters have different heights but have the same width and are stacked one above the other.

When I try,

```
ax = fig.add_axes([0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.text(x, y1, 'C', fontsize=40)
ax.text(x, y2, 'T', fontsize=20)
```

'T' will be smaller in both height and width.

Is there a way to create 'text' in matplotlib with specific height and width? I am assuming that there is an alternate way (other than fontsize) to define the overall dimensions of a matplotlib text area.

Comment: create bitmap/image with logo. it is standard method to keep logo. use some bitmap program like GIMP or vector program like Inkscape.

Comment: @furas, I am required to create these logos (with several lines of these characters) dynamically/programmatically as part of a broader python pipeline. While my understanding of 'python plugin for gimp' is limited, I was of the impression that we can use it to only edit an image that we already created. Am I correct?